# adb shell error : app_process not found

Tags: android, windows, adb, android-debug

While trying to run simple adb commands such as `adb shell pm` im receiving the following error : `/system/bin/pm[6] : app_process : not found`. The device is not rooted, but it should run `pm` anyway. I wonder what is the problem, any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: `pm` is a shell script located at /system/bin. which calls java `pm` jar file using `app_process` utility. The error says `app_process` not found in its path.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this problem after some update. As a workaround run this prior to `pm` command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/system/bin/
```

Comment: This hasn't fixed the issue for me. /system/bin is already in my $PATH, otherwise the pm command wouldn't work. The app_process file does exist within that folder, so I don't understand why it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

are you using `scripts` or `bins` in your `vendor` (partition)?

If so, `env` is based on `vendor_sh`, which is overridden by "`vendor/bin:vendor/xbin`". You can try "`./vendor/bin/sh`" and then "`echo $ PATH`" to verify.

If u export `system/bin` to vendor_sh before your "`pm`", I think it should work.

```
    cc_binary {
    name: "sh_vendor",
    defaults: ["sh-defaults"],
    stem: "sh",
    vendor: true,
    cflags: [
        // Additional flags for vendor variant
        "-UMKSH_DEFAULT_PROFILEDIR",
        "-UMKSHRC_PATH",
        "-UMKSH_DEFAULT_EXECSHELL",
        "-DMKSH_DEFAULT_PROFILEDIR=\"/vendor/etc\"",
        "-DMKSHRC_PATH=\"/vendor/etc/mkshrc\"",
        "-DMKSH_DEFAULT_EXECSHELL=\"/vendor/bin/sh\"",
        "-DMKSH_DEFPATH_OVERRIDE=\"/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin\"",
    ],  
}
```